# How to create looping healthcheck and grab enum value for prometheus client

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, prometheus

Following this example: https://opensource.com/article/18/4/metrics-monitoring-and-python

We are using Python to try and create a healthcheck app that scrapes a webpage and tests for a successful login. We then wish to send the state of the healthcheck to Prometheus, using the prometheus_client package.

We have `app.py` which is basically the Flask api endpoint where Prometheus will scrape metrics. We also came up with the idea of spawning a subprocess to run our infinite test loop.

```py
from flask import Flask, Response
from middleware import setup_metrics
import prometheus_client
import subprocess

CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST = str('text/plain; version=0.0.4; charset=utf-8')
app = Flask(__name__)
setup_metrics(app)
subprocess.Popen(['python', "/usr/src/tasks/selenium_login.py"])

@app.route('/metrics')
def metrics():
    return Response(
        prometheus_client.generate_latest(),
        mimetype=CONTENT_TYPE_LATEST)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start up the server to expose the metrics.
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', debug=True)  # local host
```

We have `middleware.py` which calculates and reports metrics

```py
from flask import request
from prometheus_client import Counter, Histogram
import time
import sys

HEALTHCHECK_STATE = Enum(
    'my_task_state',
    'Description of enum: healthcheck state',
    states=['starting', 'running', 'stopped'])


 def set_state_to_running():
     HEALTHCHECK_STATE.state('running')


 def set_state_to_stopped():
     HEALTHCHECK_STATE.state('stopped')


def setup_metrics(app):
    app.after_request(post_state)
```

We have `selenium_login.py` which runs the test login script and either passes or exceptions out.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import base64
from middleware import set_state_to_running, set_state_to_stopped


def login():

    time.sleep(20)

    try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get('webpage.com')
        # do login stuff
        driver.quit()

        set_state_to_running()
    except:
        set_state_to_stopped()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        login()
```

Problem we are trying to solve is passing the state from the `selenium_login.py` file to `middleware.py` so that the metric updates as the infinite login loop runs and either passes or fails. So far hitting the metrics endpoint only yields us:

```
my_task_state{my_task_state="starting"} 1.0
my_task_state{my_task_state="running"} 0.0
my_task_state{my_task_state="stopped"} 0.0
```

We would expect running to be a "1.0". Can someone help us with the logic here?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to run the login as a separate script. Try to run the test on a separate threat but still within the same script:

```py
def infinite_loop():
    while True:
        login()
        time.sleep(20)

thread = Thread(target=infinite_loop,
                        args=(),
                        kwargs={})
thread.daemon = True
thread.start()
```

This way you will have access to all the elements you define on your main script